# Shading Problems

Tags: shaders, lighting

The shading on the side of this object and the shading on the front is stuffed, please explain how to fix. (Model download below image).

[image]

https://mega.nz/#!TFRl1ICS!Wj-04U8aDDYum2wVFK2kxnwucKQXv6Neg9imJzsXZ3Q

Comment: Research smooth shading, flat shading, edge split and bevel.

Comment: @Leander Already tried...

Comment: Your model is a mess, it has awful topology, uneven mesh density, lots of ngons, internal faces, non manifold geometry and lots of duplicate geometry. Do a serious clean up to your mesh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It's better to just redo the whole thing. I've tried to clean it up and it's counterproductive. And Battleredwing keep the topology quad only.

Comment: @Battleredwing This is topology you will want to aim for: http://imgur.com/bvYFbzs